# Can Someone please explain me the logic of calculating big-O in my example

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o

It is said the complexity of selection sort is O(N^2) but i don't get the logic since i'm reducing the number of times the loop executed. I understand for Code block 2 but not for code block 1

```
public int[] Sorting(int[] array)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= array.Length - 1; i++)
    {           
        minimum=i;
        for (j = i; j < array.Length-1; j++) 
        {
            if (array[minimum] > array[j+1])
                minimum = j + 1;
        }   
        int temp = array[minimum];
        array[minimum] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}
```

---

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++) //Code 2
{
    for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
```

Comment: It would help everyone immensely if you formatted your code with proper indentations.

Comment: can you show me an example please sorry i'm new @Igor

Comment: @nevas I just edited the post when Igor posted his comment. Please refresh the page and you see the proper indentations.

Comment: I know in this editor i need to leave space 4 times to make a code snippet but if i add text then it is shown as a normal text @Amy

Comment: @nevas - click on the [edit] link of your question to see the new text provided by hankide, that should illustrate how you need to format any code supplied.

Comment: @hankide thanks i thought he asked me to edit the code in such a way that two code blocks are in same snippet i tried that it did not work for me but thanks once again

Comment: @nevas Every line must be indented 4 spaces to be interpreted as code.  Another 4 spaces indents the code by four spaces.  If the "normal text" is supposed to be code, then it needs to be indented as well.

Comment: @Amy I did not get "Another 4 spaces indents the code by four spaces. If the "normal text" is supposed to be code, then it needs to be indented as well"  i did not understand this but sorry for the inconvenience i caused i'll rectify this issue As soon as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `n` be the array size.

And look at the number of comparison (calls to `if (array[minimum] > array[j+1])`).

- For *i=0* it's called *n-1* times.
- For *i=1* it's called *n-2* times.
- ...
- For *i=n-1* it's called *0* times.

Finally, it's called 0+1+...+(n-1) times.

It's the [sum of consecutive integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

And, in your case, it's `(n-1)*n/2` which is `O(n²)`

**Edit**:

So the exact number of comparison is `(n-1)*n/2`, it's not exactly `n²`, it's look better than `n²`, but it's really not.

- For n=10 you have 45 comparisons.
- For n=100 you have 4950 comparisons.

That it, for 10 times more entry, you take > 100 times more times to complete your algorithm.

- For n=10 you have 45 comparisons.
- For n=1000 you have 499500 comparisons.

That it, for 100 times more entry, you take > 10 000 times more times to complete your algorithm.

As you can see, when you multiply by **k** the number of entry, you multiply roughly by **k²** the computation time.

Comment: Thanks. but if we say n times then it means the loop is executed n times  and assuming n=5 it is executed 5 times now when we say   n^2 then it means 25 combination is there that is fine in code block 2 but in code block 1 when n is 5 j is executed around 15 times that's where i'm not getting it

Comment: @nevas, Big-O notation is not about exact numbers, it's about asymptotic.

Comment: @Dale but then when do we decide that a certain change is agreeable like if j loop is divided in half then it would be logn but here the number of time is getting reduced in certain series so that should be taken into consideration. I may be extremely wrong  but help me a little please

Comment: @nevas In your example the number of operations `T(n)` is proportional to `(n-1)*n/2 = n^2/2 - n/2`. But for large enough values of `n` the only significant part of this expression is `n^2/2`. Constants can be omitted as well when we talk about big-O notation. Thus, the result is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Dale what you are saying is 10+7+8..n so (n+1)*(n/2) so it is good in this situation but what would be the code block 2's Big O notation

Comment: Big O notation is about asymptotic behavior: what happen when n goes to ∞. Both of your code execution time is roughly λ.n² when n goes to ∞. (roughly mean that the quotient ExecTime(n)/(λ.n²) goes to 1 when n goes to ∞). We don't care that λ=0.5 (block 1) or λ=1 (block 2), both executions times fit to a parabola when we look at ∞. That the meaning of O(n²): executions times fit to a parabola when we look at ∞. Which is not optimal for a sort algorithm.